# Separating redirection logic in angular pages

Tags: angular5

In my application we have a summary page having a link to take the user to the different pages of the application. For example, we have separate pages for collecting personal details, address details, education details etc., and there is a summary page giving the summary of a student's data. Users of the application will go to the summary page and then navigate to any individual pages in case if the data is not filled up yet. After the user goes to the individual page, they can enter the required details, and upon saving the entered details, they will be eventually redirected back to the summary page.

I have implemented the above functionality as below at the moment,

- When the user clicks on a link to the address details page from the summary page, I will pass the redirect url as a query string to the summary page, and upon the user saves the address details in the address page, I will redirect the user back to the summary page using the redirect url passed on the query string.
- Each individual pages have a common base class
- Redirection logic is present in each individual pages now. This logic checks if there was a redirection url present in the query string, then if present it will direct the user to the summary page after the user clicks on the save button on the current page.

I feel the above solution is elementary, there is potential for adding new pages to our application.

I wonder if there is anyway to implement the above requirement in a elegant way in such a way that the redirection logic is separated as a angular service, route   or any other angular technique so that we dont have to do any thing extra for the new pages that will be added in the future.

Comment: your tags has `angularJS` and `angular5` . Please be specific about which version. both have diff implementation. I think you are talking about `angularJS`, is it ? Also, are you using `$routeProvider` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am using anugular5.